# View not loading for Asynchronous Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a program for Asynchronous Controller. But unfortunately not able to execute the program. While running the program  it says -

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.

Following is the code for controller -

```
public class AsyncDemoController : AsyncController
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public void IndexAysnc()
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment(2);
        Operation1();
        Operation2();            
    }

    public ActionResult IndexCompleted(string Operation1, string Operation2)
    {
        ViewData["Operation1"] = Operation1;
        ViewData["Operation2"] = Operation2;
        return View("Index");
    }

    void Operation1()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["Operation1"] = "Result1";
        }

        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    }

    void Operation2()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["Operation2"] = "Result2";
        }

        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    }
}
```

I must be missing something. Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What url you are using to access the index page ?

Comment: I tried "AsyncDemo\Index". But no go.

Comment: Why you are using async controller ? tell me your use case and i may provide you with a better solution.